# save data while procces array in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array and i need process them. While task is running i need to save some information to send through ajax. I use async module, but don't do what i need.

Example:

```
var sendData = new Array();
async.each(mails, function(item) {
  var mail = item.trim();
  console.log(mail);
  User.find({mail: mail},function(err, user){

     if (user.length > 0) {
              sendMail(mail);                 
              var reg = new REG({mail: mail, resp:"Send Mail"});
              reg.save(function(err){
                   if(!err){
                     var dat ={success: true,msg: "Seccess!"}; 
                     sendData.push(dat); 
                   }
                });   
        }else{
            var dat ={success: false,msg: "Error!"}; 
            sendData.push(dat);
       }

  });


  }, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("ERROR");
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log("sendResp");
  console.log(sendData);
  res.send(sendData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sendData = new Array();
async.each(mails, function(item,callback) {
var mail = item.trim();
console.log(mail);
User.find({mail: mail},function(err, user){

 if (user.length > 0) {
          sendMail(mail);                 
          var reg = new REG({mail: mail, resp:"Send Mail"});
          reg.save(function(err){
               if(!err){
                 var dat ={success: true,msg: "Seccess!"}; 
                 sendData.push(dat); 
               }
            });   
    }else{
        var dat ={success: false,msg: "Error!"}; 
        sendData.push(dat);
   }
   callback();
});
}, function(err) {
if (err) {
    console.log("ERROR");
    console.log(err);
}
console.log("sendResp");
console.log(sendData);
res.send(sendData);
});
```

wish this can help u!